# Sumar filas usando Inner Join en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

- Defectos - con las columnas `codigo`, `producto`, `cantidad`, `fecha`
- Produccion - con las columnas `codigo`, `producto`, `cantidad`, `fecha`

Quiero formar Query donde me muestre la suma de los defectos agrupados por mes, y que al lado salga la suma de la producción para el mes correspondiente

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha),SUM(cantidad) FROM defectos GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
```

Con eso me muestra la suma de los defectos agrupadas por mes, pero no logro traer la suma de la produccion en la misma query

```
ENERO    5
FEBRERO  6
MARZO    25
```

Estoy probando con esta Query:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(d.fecha),SUM(d.defecto) FROM defectos d
INNER JOIN
id_conformado c
ON MONTH(c.fecha) = MONTH(c.fecha)
GROUP BY MONTH(d.fecha)
```

Pero tengo el problema de que se alteran los valores de la suma y solo suma cuando hay una fecha igual en la tabla produccion

Comment: Interesaría que pusieses un ejemplo de los datos que hay en las tablas para que saliesen esos resultados que muestras, para hacernos una idea más clara de lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armas dos subconsultas para `defectos` y `produccion` y las relacionas mediante el mes.

```
SELECT  P.MES,
        D.CANTIDAD           as DEFECTOS,
        IFNULL(P.CANTIDAD,0) as PRODUCCION
        FROM ( 
            SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha) as MES, 
                   SUM(cantidad)    as CANTIDAD
                   FROM defectos 
                   GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
        ) D
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha) as MES,
                   SUM(cantidad)    as CANTIDAD
                   FROM produccion 
                   GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
        ) P
        ON D.MES = P.MES
```

Esto tiene una eventual limitación, ¿que ocurre si un mes no has tenido defectos? pierdes completamente la fila, no ves la cantidad de `produccion`. Si este fuera el caso, es conveniente pivotear sobre una tabla que deberías construir previamente, con los nombres de los 12 meses y hacer que ambas subconsultas pivoteen mediante un `LEFT JOIN` sobre la misma.

Comment: Patricio, creo que tu respuesta es la que mas se acerca a lo que quiero, pero tengo un problema que lo dejare en una respuesta a mi propia pregunta.

Comment: Sii, según lo que me dices pensé en ese problema, si no hay defectos se pierde la fila, la tabla con los meses del año como puedo construirla en la misma consulta ? , o debo construirla de forma permanente en el apartado de tablas de la misma base de datos

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon, lo ideal es tener una tabla física con los 12 nombres de mes , así como te los presenta `MONTHNAME()` , y harías luego u `FROM` sobre esta tabla, con `LEFT JOIN` a las otras dos.

Comment: Estimado eh creado la tabla llamada meses con su respectivos campos id,mes quedando 1-ENERO,2-FEBRERO...... Al hacer el Left Join hacia la tabla defectos no tengo problema, me muestra 0 defectos en aquellos meses donde no hay registros, pero al agregar el Left Join hacia la tabla produccion, se pierden los meses en aquellos donde no hay prroduccion

Comment: Estimado, deseo hacer la misma Query, pero esta ves que me muestre los defectos por maquinas y por mes, es decir Maquina 1 ENERO FEBRERO MARZO.... Maquina 2 ENERO FEBRERO MARZO.... y así sucesivamente, ademas de ir mostrando la suma de los defectos como lo puse mas arriba en la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, lo que buscas no es un **INNER JOIN**, si no un **UNION ALL**.

Al hacer un **INNER JOIN**, comparando por mes, te va a sacar más registros de la cuenta, ya que cada registro de defecto del mes 7 va a crearte un resultado por cada registro que haya en producto del mismo mes, y luego los va a sumar todos.

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(T.fecha), SUM(T.cantidad) FROM (
SELECT d.fecha as fecha,d.cantidad as cantidad FROM tabla1 d
UNION ALL
SELECT c.fecha as fecha,c.cantidad as cantidad FROM tabla2 c
 ) AS T GROUP BY MONTH(fecha);
```

Si no, y los quieres separados por producto o defecto:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(T.fecha), SUM(T.cantidad), SUM(T.cantidads) FROM (
SELECT d.fecha as fecha,d.cantidad as cantidad, 0 as cantidads FROM tabla1 d
UNION ALL
SELECT c.fecha as fecha, 0 as cantidad ,c.cantidad as cantidads FROM tabla2 c
 ) AS T GROUP BY MONTH(fecha);
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Buena respuesta. Aunque quizás por tema de rendimiento, en lugar de hacer un `union all` directo de los registros, lo haría de la agrupación de cada tabla. Es decir, para cada tabla hacemos su `SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha),SUM(cantidad) FROM ... GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)`, luego el union all de ambos resultados y finalmente volvemos a agrupar.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de todos, eh conseguido lograr la QUERY que necesitaba, en este caso es mostrar la suma de cada tipo de defecto por cada mes según un año en especifico. Para luego ser comparado con la producción en dicho mes, para así obtener el % de merma. Ademas de totalizar cada columna. Les adjunto la QUERY por si en el futuro les sirve.

```
SELECT M.mes,IFNULL(D.manchas,0) AS manchas,IFNULL(D.humedad,0) AS humedad,IFNULL(D.suciedad,0) AS suciedad,IFNULL(D.deslaminado,0) AS deslaminado,IFNULL(D.malforrado,0) AS malforrado,IFNULL(D.quemadas,0) AS quemadas,IFNULL(D.descentrado,0) AS descentrado,IFNULL(D.desgarre,0) AS desgarre,IFNULL(D.otros,0) AS otros,IFNULL(D.faltapapel,0) AS faltapapel,IFNULL(D.totalmensual,0) AS totaLmensual,IFNULL(P.produccion,0) as totalproduccion, IFNULL(ROUND(((D.totalmensual/(D.totalmensual+P.produccion))*100),2),0) as totalmerma
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM meses
)M
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(fecha) as id,SUM(manchas) as manchas,SUM(humedad) AS humedad,SUM(suciedad) AS suciedad,SUM(deslaminado) AS deslaminado,SUM(malforrado) AS
    malforrado,SUM(quemadas) AS quemadas,SUM(descentrado) AS descentrado,SUM(desgarre) AS desgarre,SUM(otros) AS otros,SUM(faltapapel) AS faltapapel,
    SUM(manchas+humedad+suciedad+deslaminado+malforrado+quemadas+descentrado+desgarre+otros+faltapapel) AS totalmensual 
    FROM defectos 
    WHERE YEAR(fecha) = '2020' 
    GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
) D
ON M.id = D.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(fecha) as id,SUM(produccion) as produccion 
    FROM id_conformado 
    WHERE YEAR(fecha) = '2020'
    GROUP BY MONTH(fecha)
) P
ON M.id = p.id
UNION
SELECT T.nombre,T.manchas,T.humedad,T.suciedad,T.deslaminado,T.malforrado,T.quemadas,T.descentrado,T.desgarre,T.otros,T.faltapapel,T.totaldefectos,T.totalproduccion,
IFNULL(ROUND(((T.totaldefectos/(T.totaldefectos+T.totalproduccion))*100),2),0) as totalmerma 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'TOTAL MENSUAL' AS nombre,SUM(manchas) AS manchas,SUM(humedad) AS humedad,SUM(suciedad) As suciedad,SUM(deslaminado) AS deslaminado,SUM(malforrado) AS malforrado,
    SUM(quemadas) AS quemadas,SUM(descentrado) AS descentrado,SUM(desgarre) AS desgarre,SUM(otros) AS otros,SUM(faltapapel) AS faltapapel,
    SUM(manchas+humedad+suciedad+deslaminado+malforrado+quemadas+descentrado+desgarre+otros+faltapapel) as totaldefectos,
    (SELECT SUM(produccion) FROM id_conformado WHERE YEAR(fecha) = '2020') AS totalproduccion 
    FROM defectos
    WHERE YEAR(fecha) = '2020'
)T
```

[image: Resultado Final]